# Dired+ missing from MELPA

Tags: dired, package-repositories

I am trying to install dired+ from MELPA but it seems that it no longer is listed.
I also checked here: https://melpa.org/

Is this normal?

Comment: I'd like to piggy-back two follow-up questions primarily for @Drew, but for others also : 1) Is there a mechanism to be apprised of ?(important )updates to your emacswiki packages? 2) Do you have and could you share a ?(partial )list of the 'locked' emacswiki packages?

Comment: @user1404316 I suggest you open a new question for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is true that MELPA no longer pulls libraries from EmacsWiki.

**Please obtain [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus#Dired%2b) and other libraries by me from EmacsWiki: [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).**

All of my pages on EmacsWiki are locked (they require a site administrator to unlock them).  There has never been an actual security problem reported, AFAIK.

Yes, it is true that a locked web page does not present the same level of security as a digital signature (such as is used for GIT).  On the other hand, the fact that some code is digitally signed and pulled from a GIT repository is no guarantee at all that the code is not malicious or accidentally harmful.

(Here's a thought: If someone did want to propagate
poison code, do you think they would prefer to do so
from EmacsWiki, which has few downloads, or from a
site like MELPA, which has many times more?  From a
site where you need to fiddle a bit to download and
"install" a library, or from a site where you can
do that willy-nilly and quickly, without thought or
effort?)

If you obtain one of my libraries elsewhere than from EmacsWiki, including from https://github.com/emacsmirror/, then you will get an *old version* that doesn't benefit from maintenance (bug fixes, enhancements). The version of `dired+.el` that is on that mirror dates from November 2017. The version on EmacsWiki dates from January 2018. And I'm not even sure that that mirror will continue to be updated at all from now on.

[Library [`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el) is now available also from a new GitHub mirror, [here](https://github.com/steckerhalter/highlight.el).  The maintainer of that mirror will keep it up-to-date, to reflect the latest version from the wiki.]

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: If it wasn't you, then perhaps we were both struck by the same phantom downvoter. :) I've tweaked the wording in my answer to make it more objective, as I know next to nothing about EmacsWiki and its security policy.

Comment: (IOW, I never intended to make a claim on its security from personal authority.)

Comment: FWIW In the case of EmacsWiki packages other than yours (Drew's) there was an actual security issue, since the pages were (and still are) globally editable. For instance it seems that if I wanted to, I could edit [ac-dabbrev](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ac-dabbrev.el) or [goto-chg](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/goto-chg.el) without any problems, even though I'm not an author or contributor to these libraries. Since packages are automatically pulled by MELPA, malicious changes would have been easily propagated to any users who upgraded their packages.

Comment: @aplaice: Yes, agreed. But MELPA maintainers were aware of that difference. Note too that there are plenty of places, including emacs.SE! and useful blogs, where people copy code that they then use in their init files and such. Many such places are about as much a security risk as are the non-locked Emacs Wiki pages. I'd be willing to bet that some of those who are behind keeping wiki code out of MELPA post such clippable code that others then copy+paste. ;-)

Comment: I agree that snippets on Emacswiki are probably about as bad as other sources of copy-pastable code (in some ways worse, in some better). However, unlocked Emacswiki *libraries*, even not as a source for MELPA, are (IMO) still more of a security risk than emacs.SE or blogs, because they're generally far longer and presented as complete/standalone.

Comment: @aplaice Not just that - the whole system of semi-automatic package upgrades enabled by repositories like MELPA and package managers like `package.el` results in code being installed without users commonly reviewing every update. This is the main reason why source/content validation/verification are so important.

Comment: @Basil: I agree that if people are going to just start using something without looking at it then that's not great. That's not great even if the something is digitally signed. It's fine with me if the only users of my code know enough Lisp to use `require` and `load-path` and have to go to the trouble of downloading the source code. I even prefer that they actually take a look at it - the Commentary, at least. Blind inclusion of stuff is not my idea of ideal Emacs users. Feedback from users who pay attention is also better, IMO.

Comment: @Drew I agree, but we are now venturing into "I like green more than I like blue" territory. Re: getting eyes to look at code - in most package distribution systems that's up to the trusted "wardens" of the repository, not the end users. Re: ideal users - we don't get to choose them, but we do get to design how software is distributed, and there's a lot of work to be done there in Emacs land.

Comment: @Basil: `package.el` and its repositories vastly increase the number of users of 3rd-party code, and the users are not obliged to know Lisp or look at the code they're using. That's a plus and a minus. I'm just agreeing with your statement that "*This is the main reason why source/content validation/verification are so important.*" 100% agreement - that is indeed the problem. **MELPA et al do not at all provide such validation/verification.** There (currently, at least) is no substitute for user eyeballs sanity-checking code that users use. Users of Emacs wiki are more likely to do that.

Comment: @Drew I am also agreeing with you - hence the need for work to be done; I just can't help being pedantic. :)

Comment: Does that mean we need to manually update Dired+ everytime? Including manually check the wiki for updates? Or is there something I don't know about EmacsWiki?

Comment: @DidierA.: It means that *if* you want the latest version of [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el) then you need to download it from the wiki. Using Dired+ is optional, as is using the latest version.

Answer (score 8):

> Is this normal?

Yes, MELPA recently updated its policy and no longer includes packages hosted on [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/), quoting security reasons: https://github.com/melpa/melpa/pull/5008. See also [Drew's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38560/15748).

For now you will have to install it either from its upstream EmacsWiki source at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired%2b.el or from its (potentially outdated) [Emacsmirror](https://emacsmirror.net/) clone at https://github.com/emacsmirror/dired-plus.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it using [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get). What worked for me, step by step:

1. Tried installing `el-get` from melpa, then ran into all kinds of weirdnesses, e.g. [1982](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/issues/1982).
2. So I opted for the [basic setup](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get#basic-setup) by adding to my `~/.emacs`:

   ```
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")
   (unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)
     (with-current-buffer
         (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el")
       (goto-char (point-max))
       (eval-print-last-sexp)))
   (add-to-list 'el-get-recipe-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get-user/recipes")
   (el-get 'sync)
   ```
3. Restarted Emacs.
4. **M-x el-get-emacswiki-build-local-recipes**
5. **M-x el-get-install dired+**
6. Added to my `~/.emacs`:

   ```
   (require 'dired+)
   ```

To update the package: **M-x el-get-update dired+**

Comment: As of December 2022 this is still valid. `el-get` is still quite remarkable.